# What is the correct way for a Drupal 8 custom theme to override the JS collection renderer?

Tags: theming, 8

I would like to implement a custom theme, and in my theme, I need to change the way that JavaScript is rendered. By default, Drupal 8 will use the Drupal\Core\Asset\JsCollectionRenderer class, and create a bunch of html_tag render arrays.

I want to change this to allow returning just the name of the JS file, so I can present it in a different way using Twig.

It would appear that I need to define a ServiceProvider class that can register a change to asset.js.collection_renderer (core.services.yml), and implement a custom class to replace JsCollectionRenderer's behaviour.

However, it looks as though I would need a custom module in order to get the ServiceProvider's register() method to fire.

If possible, I wanted to avoid needing a custom module just to have a custom theme, because that seems like needless overhead, so I'm wondering if there's a way to fully encapsulate this behaviour in a single theme, or whether my approach is misguided in some way and there's a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Themes have no mechanism to provider or alter services. A custom module is needed.